# Chutzpah's "Open in browser" option does nothing

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, chutzpah

I have Chutzpah for Visual Studio 2013 installed.  I have a fresh install of windows and VS so when I selected the "Open in browser" option to run my tests in a browser, it asked me which browser I wanted to use.  I selected Google Chrome Canary and an error message came up.  I dismissed the dialog to try it again.  Unfortunately, I did not record the error message.  I no longer get an error when I select that option.  As a matter of fact absolutely nothing happens when I select that option.  No browser, no error, nothing.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin but the exact same thing happens.

Does anyone know how to reassociate the browser or how to do a fresh install and have it ask me again?  I'm not even sure if it is a chutzpah or a windows thing.  I am running Windows 8.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this extension to change the default browser: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5

Comment: I have since switched to a new laptop and no longer have this problem.  I will mark this as a solution because I think it would have probably fixed the problem.